# Support of Matlis dual

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $(A,m)$ be a commutative noetherian local ring,
$E$ the injective hull of $A/m$, and $M$ a finitely generated $A$-module.

What is the connection between the support of $M$ and the support of the Matlis dual $M^* = Hom_A(M,E)$? are they the same? do they have the same Krull dimension?

Comment: The Matlis dual is an artinian module over the completion $(\hat{A},\hat{m})$ of $(A,m)$. The support of the Matlis dual is thus obviously reduced to $\{\hat{m}\}$ (or $\emptyset$ if $M=0$).

Comment: However, an article by Melkersson & Schenzel,and a later one by Andrew Richardson, deal with dual notions of *co-support* that are more suited to artiinian modules than support is.